# datatables.min.css doesn't work from local project

Tags: css, web, datatables, styles

I have a ASP.NET MVC project which uses JQuery Datatables to show a table.
The problem: the css stylesheet isn't applied when links to local css file. I've tried the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/datatables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/datatables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/datatables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/datatables.min.css" />
```

But this one (at the same place of my HTML) is working:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css" />
```

Even current sorting column highlight from this css doesn't work!

Of course, the CSS file exists in my project's Content folder, and its contents is totally the same, because I even try to copy the file from https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css and put it in project's Content folder.

So, the question is why doesn't the first HTML link snippet work?
Maybe, a bug in the MVC (it's up to date)?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery DataTables distribution includes CSS, JS and image files (in the `images` folder).

Use [Download builder](https://datatables.net/download/index), select **Download** tab and download all required files.

Also you should not use `~` in your URL. Most likely that is the reason why CSS is not applied. Use absolute URL `/Content/datatables.min.css` or relative URL `Content/datatables.min.css` instead.

Comment: It was done already. I have icons in my project as well as CSS and JS files. But CSS isn't applied if I set it locally from the project folder - i have to set it from link https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css . Thus, I lose abuility to change it.

Comment: @Laser42, It doesn't seem correct. You should not use `~` in URL. Use absolute URL `/Content/datatables.min.css` or relative URL instead.

Comment: Thank you, but nothing helps. I tried to use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Datatables/datatables.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Datatables/datatables.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Datatables/datatables.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Datatables/datatables.css" />`,but there it does not work. (If I do it with bootstrap.css, it does work!)

Comment: I have also tried complete reinstall of datatables through the download link, put it in the reccomended folder (Datatables) in the root of my project - still no result.

Comment: And the same problem when adding style through bundles